# calculator with modular function

Tags: modular-arithmetic, calculator, modular-function

I am looking to buy a calculator with Modular exponentiation functions and vendors do not mention this function in their websites I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me find a good calculator

Comment: Do you mean a table calculator ?

Comment: @Peter no scientific

Comment: @Milad Rad You don't need to buy a calculator to do it - [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) can do it as well, you can see some examples [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=13%5E579+mod+246) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=57%5E9135+mod+468).

Comment: @TobyMak Yes doing it online is very fast but I can't use online calculators for exams I need a good calculator for my cryptography exam

Comment: @MiladRad I'm sorry to hear that - the fastest method I can think of using a scientific calculator is to write the exponent in binary form, then apply the modulo on each of those parts and simplify.